# How can I write custom handlebars in Ember js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

js:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('demo-helper', function (property, options) {
    console.log('demo helper');
    return '<li><a> '+ msg+'</a></li>';
});
```

hbs :

`{{#demo-helper}} msg {{/demo-helper}}`

How can I wrap hi (inner html of handlebar) with any custom tag?.I know that component has tag parameter that encapsulates html with given tag. But it supports only one tag. I want to encapsulate with multiple tags like

```
<li><a>innerhtml</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of what you want to achieve? Pseudo code is fine.

Comment: Also, what version of Ember are you using? `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper` is quite old.

Answer (score 1):

This is what components are for. They have can have an arbitrarily sized template. You can use {{yield}} to nest other html inside the component.

See https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/.

component template:

`<div><div><div>{{yield}}</div></div></div>`

usage:

`{{#my-component}} Hello world {{/my-component>}}`

Components are very powerful and have many other options, see the guides for more info. They are the best resource.

Comment: But in my case, <div><div><div> will be varying. It may be just <li>.I can't create another component for this variation. But the yield portion will be the same. Ember just supports one tag. But I need multiple nested html tags.I am aware of yield.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you want, then.

Comment: I have to create a component just to wrap a HTML content. If I want to wrap with another type of tag,let's say <ul> I have to create another component just to wrap.I want to wrap component dynamically. using tagName I can specify one HTML tag.I want to wrap with multiple HTML tags.